# Jest Returning False when expecting True

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test a component in React using Jest and Enzyme.

I'd like to asset that my Navigation component is rendering out NavItems.

**Test:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

import Navigation from '../src/components/navigation/Navigation';
import NavItem from '../src/components/navigation/NavItem';

describe('.Navigation Component', () => {
  it('should contain NavItem', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Navigation />);
    console.log(wrapper.debug());
    expect(wrapper.contains(<NavItem {...mockNavitem} />)).toEqual(true);
  });
});

const mockNavitem = { href: 'foo', text: 'bar', activeClass: 'boo' };
```

**Navigation Component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import NavItem from './NavItem';

const navItems = [
  {
    id: 0,
    href: '/',
    text: 'Home',
    activeClass: '',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    href: '/page-two',
    text: 'Page Two',
    activeClass: '',
  },
];

const Navigation = () => (
  <ul>
    {navItems.map(item => (
      <li key={item.id}>
        <NavItem {...item} />
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);

export default Navigation;
```

NavItems Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const NavItem = ({ href, text, activeClass }) => (
  <NavLink to={href} activeClassName={activeClass}>
    {text}
  </NavLink>
);

NavItem.propTypes = {
  href: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  activeClass: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default NavItem;
```

The output from the test runner is as follows:

```
 FAIL  __tests__/Navigation.test.jsx
  ● Console

    console.log __tests__/Navigation.test.jsx:10
      <ul>
        <li>
          <NavItem id={0} href="/" text="Home" activeClass="" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavItem id={1} href="/page-two" text="Page Two" activeClass="" />
        </li>
      </ul>

  ● .Navigation Component › should contain NavItem

    expect(received).toEqual(expected)

    Expected value to equal:
      true
    Received:
      false
```

I have added a console log statement to output the component, I can see it in the results, however it does not seem to be a valid test.

I am very new to react / jest so am probably making a very n00b mistake.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try traversing down the `Navigation` component to find `NavItem`.

```
expect(wrapper.find(NavItem)).toHaveLength(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping with this :)

I've made the changes you suggested, the test still fails however, this time with an error as show here - https://ibb.co/dRt1Km

Comment: I made a mistake, it's been edited, you can try again